# How can i make the command line remember or store references

Tags: mysql, command-line, window

I am starting to use the command line, to connect to MYSQL, change directory (am very beginnerish)

When working with directories, most times the directories are very long, like:

```
C:\Users\user> cd c:/storage/space1/create/web/projects/app4/public

C:\Users\user> c:/wamp64/bin/mysql/mysql5.7.11/bin/mysql -u root -p
```

So when I close the command line window and re-open it, I will have to type the entire thing over again, so I was wondering if there was a way to store variable or make the the command line remember like.

```
C:\Users\user> cd app4pub

C:\Users\user> connect_mysql or C:\Users\user> mysqlDir -u root -p
```

Comment: I am not familiar with MS-Windows, but doesn't that command line offer a command history like any shell on any other system? Have a try using the cursor up key...

Comment: Put them in a .bat file and run that.

Answer (score 0):

create toslqdir.bat file with  below content and run it

```
set Pathname = c:/storage/space1/create/web/projects/app4/public
cd %Pathname%
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using `bash`, one feature of the shell that you may want to explore is the `CTRL-R` command.  It allows you to interactively search backwards in your command history for previously issued commands that contain a given string.  It does this search immediately, so that if you add or delete characters it will adjust what it finds.  Once you find the `cd` command you want, then you can hit `Enter` or other editing commands and it will put that command right into your command line prompt for you.

It is a bit confusing to see when you first use it, but it is very handy once you get used to it.

There are other commands (`CTRL-N`, `CTRL-P` to pull the next or previous command, etc.)Check out [this article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-bash-history-commands-and-expansions-on-a-linux-vps) for more information.

Another pair of `bash` built-in commands you should check out are `pushd` and `popd`  the first one performs a `cd` command, but also places the destination directory in a stack so that you can later `popd` to get back where you were.  I have used these for years and use the following in my `.bash_aliases`

```
alias cd=pushd
alias bk=popd
```

then I can `cd` to where I want to go (long name) and `bk` back to where I was without having to type the destination all the time.  It also give me fewer `cd` command in my command history to wade through with my `CTRL-R` searches.